# How to find the difference between two arraylist values in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
static ArrayList random_ints=new ArrayList();
static ArrayList mean_storage=new ArrayList();
static ArrayList diff_means=new ArrayList();


random_ints = {834,438,234,124};
mean_storage = {867,459,254,189};
```

I have to find out the difference b/w these 2 array lists and store in "diff_means" array list

Comment: What did you try? Does `list.retainAll()` fits your need?

Comment: You mean to say your outcome would be like `{33,21,20,65}`?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I think the difference he  is asking for is `834-867` or vice-versa !!

Comment: @NeerajJain So the OP basically needs a `for loop`???

Comment: yeah my output like {33,21,20,65}

Comment: Unfortunately Yes , until  @Anitha clears out the confusion , **What exactly is the definition of `Difference`** according to user !!!

Comment: @AnithaTadekoru And what don't you understand? `list.getAt(n)` gives you the `nth` element. `list.getAt(n)` + a substraction and a for loop. This is all you need.

Comment: needed @ArnaudDenoyelle

Comment: I mean subtraction of the two array list values @ Neeraj Jain

Comment: @AnithaTadekoru , Ok Answer Posted

Answer (score 1):

if your requirement is `absolute difference` between the ***list's element*** values then

## Try This

```
int length=firstList.size();
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
   resultList.add(Math.abs(firstList.get(i)-secondList.get(i)));
}
```

Assuming Size of Both the list is `same` !

Comment: You mean `resultList.add`?

Answer (score 0):

So unless you are looking for a specifically *optimized* solution, you can iterate the lists, get the numbers from both input lists at a particular index and find the difference (believing that mere subtraction would do, judging which number is greater!) and add it to third list. 
You may need to handle situation where size of one list is less than other.